# How to run macro when cell value changed by formula results for code that hides/unhides rows based on formula result?

Tags: vba

I have a worksheet that hides or unhides rows based on the value as a cell. I end up getting a run time error that reads:

-2147417848 (80010108):
Method 'Hidden' of object 'Range' failed, with a yellow arrow pointing at the first Rows equation

and then another run-time error '1004':
Unable to set the hidden property of the range class.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
  Rows("1:26").EntireRow.Hidden = [a1] = 0
  Rows("27:52").EntireRow.Hidden = [a27] = 0
  Rows("53:78").EntireRow.Hidden = [a53] = 0
  Rows("79:104").EntireRow.Hidden = [a79] = 0
  Rows("105:130").EntireRow.Hidden = [a105] = 0
  Rows("131:156").EntireRow.Hidden = [a131] = 0
  Rows("157:182").EntireRow.Hidden = [a157] = 0
  Rows("183:208").EntireRow.Hidden = [a183] = 0
  Rows("209:234").EntireRow.Hidden = [a209] = 0

End Sub
```

Comment: `Worksheet_Change` isn't triggered by changes due to formulas recalculating: you need `Worksheet_Calculate` for that

Comment: I can't see your new code...

Comment: Solved! Thank you so much, wow this is great!

Comment: I switched the first line to "Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()" and it fixed it :) thanks so much @TimWilliams

Comment: Try `Me.Range("1:26").EntireRow.Hidden = [a1] = 0` etc

Comment: I switched the rows to the Me.Range as listed and its still doing the same code

Comment: This works fine for me. Is your worksheet protected? What formula is in A1 etc?  You could try adding `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the top of the routine (don't forget to set back to `True` when done)

Comment: The worksheet isn't protected, and the formula is an IF statement based on If cell x (month) is less than/= cell y (exam month), then 1, false = 0)  This code is to hide months that have a 0 reference value, but its a formulated value not a hardcoded 0

Comment: I'm out of guesses, unless you're able to share a workbook which replicates the problem.

Comment: I'd be happy too, is there an authorized method or would it be via google drive or onedrive?

Comment: Whatever works for you (but there's no method on SO for attaching files)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nvYuTFDICR5ovNxHTDsiKuzmMlsDy2Y5/view?usp=sharing                   Hey Tim, the cell in turn is the date dropdown on User dashboard N17.

Comment: When opening your file it enters a loop where the calculate event keeps triggering itself - that resolved if I added `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the top of the procedure and `Application.EnableEvents = True` at the end.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code? Im not sure how many spaces to put from start to line, or on what line in the code to place them. I can't really find anything tutortials on this specific ability of code. Thanks in advance

Comment: See my edit below

Comment: Thank you! This is awesome! Im not sure how to credit to you because its not letting me upvote it but solution verified!

Comment: Good to hear you got it working

Answer (score 0):

Should look like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate() 
    Dim v
    v = Me.Range("A1").Value
    Me.Range("1:26").EntireRow.Hidden = (v = 0)
End Sub
```

I don't know if you need to handle potential error values in the A1 formula result.

**EDIT:** try this - it looks like your worksheet is entering a loop where the hide/show is re-triggering another calculation, etc, etc

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

  On Error GoTo haveError

  Application.EnableEvents = False

  Me.Range("1:26").EntireRow.Hidden = [a1] = 0
  Me.Range("27:52").EntireRow.Hidden = [a27] = 0
  Me.Range("53:78").EntireRow.Hidden = [a53] = 0
  Me.Range("79:104").EntireRow.Hidden = [a79] = 0
  Me.Range("105:130").EntireRow.Hidden = [a105] = 0
  Me.Range("131:156").EntireRow.Hidden = [a131] = 0
  Me.Range("157:182").EntireRow.Hidden = [a157] = 0
  Me.Range("183:208").EntireRow.Hidden = [a183] = 0
  Me.Range("209:234").EntireRow.Hidden = [a209] = 0

haveError:
  Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: It came up with an Run-Time Error '1004': Unable to set the hidden property of the range class and it shut my work sheet down haha ..great :)

Comment: In addition to the above error, it's also putting up a ""Run=time error -2177417848(80010108)
 Method "hidden" of object 'range' failed." error as well

Comment: You can update your question if you have new code/errors to add

Comment: Thank you, I've updated my question, you've been very helpful!